# How can I add a UIScrollView to a View in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, view, ios6, uiscrollview

I have built a small iOS 6 app that uses a single view. However, I would like to add some more functionality and therefore need more space. I figured that the best way to do this is to add a UIScrollView.

How can I add such a UIScrollView to my View? Do I have to delete all my buttons, labels, etc. in my View, then add a UIScrollView and then put all those buttons, labels, etc. in that UIScrollView? I think that this would work but is there an easier way to do this? (Maybe without deleting all the content in my view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all views on scroll view like:

```
[scrollview addSubView:button];
```

And finally add this scrollview to main view:

```
[self.view addSubView:scrollview];
```

I think this will be helpfull. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add a view to UIScrollView without deleting buttons, labels, etc..

To add a scroll view to existing view:

1. Draw and drop the UIScroll View to the existing View
2. Select all controls in the View like Buttons, Label etc.; except UIScroll View
3. Drag all the selected component into UIScroll View

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

programmatically you have to

```
[scrollview addSubView:button];
```

instead of `[self.view addSubView:button];`

In storyboard or xib you can drag and drop the button onto the scrollview.

Hope this helps a little bit.